# Specify timeout for controller async method in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app backed by Java config and I would like to set up a default timeout for all async calls that involve Callable<> interface. For instance, consider controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public Callable<String> doSmth() {
    return () -> {
        return "myview";
    }
}
```

I would like to have a controler (per application) of how much time controller has time to do its stuff before the request times out.

I would like to have an example of *Java* config, not *xml*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and overriding `configureAsyncSupport`:

```
 @Configuration
//other annotations if needed
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(100000); //in milliseconds
        super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
    }
```

or directly on the [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/).

Comment: This will only work if it hit timeout when waiting response from database right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the default timeout of 10 secs by setting the "asyncTimeout" attribute in Tomcat's conf/server.xml configuration file:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" asyncTimeout="30000" maxThreads="1000"
    port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html