# Increase connection timeout on Spring MVC server for HTML5 audio

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, html5-audio

I have a Spring MVC Java web app which plays audio files using the HTML5 audio tag.  My MVC controller streams the audio file by writing to response.getOutputStream().

When the audio file is small (< 6mb), the browser will download the entire audio file immediately and play it without issue.  When the audio file is larger, the browser will download about 6mb and then wait until playback catches up before requesting more data.  It won't close the connection, but just wait before requesting more data from the stream.

The server will then wait for however long connectionTimeout is set on the HTTP connector in Tomcat's server.xml (default 20 seconds).  Tomcat then throws a SocketTimeoutException, ending the connection.

The browser will then play until it reaches the end of what it has downloaded and print the error ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH to the console.  This is because the browser requested the entire file but the server terminated the connection before all the data was sent.  It makes an HTTP range request for the rest of the data, opening a new connection.  This happens seamlessly and the song continues to play.  However, it shouldn't have to do this.  It should be able to keep the original connection open for the entire duration of the song.

One fix is to increase Tomcat's connectionTimeout in server.xml.  However, I would prefer to do this just for the application rather than globally for the Tomcat server.  Even better would be just for that one MVC controller method that streams the audio.  Is this possible?

Comment: this might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338516/specify-timeout-for-controller-async-method-in-spring

Comment: @Sarevok, are you able to fix the issue?